# Why is my content visible twice and JavaScript not working properly on Joomla 3.x after migrating from 1.5.26

Tags: javascript, templates, joomla, migration

after a successfull migration from Joomla 1.5.26 to 3.x incl. migrating the old genuine template I do have the problem that on some pages the content is showing twice one above the other with a slightly offset. Additionally my former superfish function for browsing and scrolling through the site based on Javascript doesn't work after the migration as well.

For a closer look:

[Look with Joomla 3.x](http://tinyurl.com/o2ns3lh)

In my 1.5.26 version it perfectly worked:

[Original look in 1.5.26](http://tinyurl.com/n67bv35)

In the index.php I did the following:

```html
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
 // Parameter aus dem Template auslesen
  $params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;
  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
  $this->language = $doc->language;
  $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
  JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
  $doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/general.css');
  $doc->addScript('/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/main.js', 'text/javascript');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" >

<head>
 <jdoc:include type="head" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/modules/mod_superfishmenu/tmpl/css/superfish.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/mootools.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/system/js/caption.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/mod_ext_superfish_menu/tmpl/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/mod_ext_superfish_menu/tmpl/js/jquery.event.hover.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/modules/mod_ext_superfish_menu/tmpl/js/superfish.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($){ $("ul.sf-menu").superfish({hoverClass:'sfHover', pathClass:'active', pathLevels:0, delay:1000, animation:{opacity:'show', height:'show'}, speed:300, autoArrows:0, dropShadows:0}) });
jQuery.event.special.hover.delay = 100;
jQuery.event.special.hover.speed = 100;
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="result-mainmenu">
    <a href="index.php"><div class="logo"></div></a>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <?php if($this->countModules('submenu')) : ?>
   <div id="submenu">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" />
      </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <div class="component">
   <jdoc:include type="component" />
 </div>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div> 
  </div>
   <div id="menu-bottom">
     <?php if($this->countModules('menu-bottom')) : ?>
    <div class="menu-bottom-container">
      <div class="menu-bottom">
           <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu-bottom" />
   </div>
       </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
  <div class="debug">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" />
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My menu in the Joomla 3.x backend looks like:

Unternehmen
     - Philosophie
       -- Erfahrung 1
          --- zurück (= back to "Erfahrung 1")
       -- Erfahrung 2
          --- zurück (= back to "Erfahrung 2")
... etc.

The "zurück" page is implemented as "external URL" with

`javascript:history.back()`

Before I already enabled JavaScript in the items.php

What causes the errors?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons I can think of that can make the content show up twice:

- Item IDs that were not migrated properly
- Modules being assigned to the wrong menu items
- An error in the template where the content is loaded twice

As for JavaScript errors - it is very important after a migration to clear all your browser's cache. Very often, the old JS libraries are loaded from the browser cache causing issues.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your point #3 solved the problem with the doubled overlaid content.

With the problem of the wrong showing links I'm still looking for an answer...